# Is it possible to render inside a functional component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to know the proper method to use `render(){}` while I'm using the functional component.

i'm new on reactjs, so far i'm always using functional component on everything :

```
const Something = () => {
}
export default Something
```

What i want is to render object which is react-scroll-parallax, while i'm using functional component, but i don't know the proper method to do that :

```
const Something = () => {
    render() {
      return (
         <ParallaxProvider>
           <Parallax className="custom-class" y={[-20, 20]} tagOuter="figure">
             <ImageBg src="../../images/wpbatik.jpg" />
           </Parallax>
         </ParallaxProvider>
      );
    }
}
export default Something
```

Thank you

Comment: In functional components there is no `render`, just return whatever you want rendered from the function.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading up more on how functional components work, e.g. https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components.  There are going to be many further differences which will require your attention, such as the component lifecycle.

Comment: This is literally the first code sample in the React.js docs under 'Components' - https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a functional component, you use `return` and it will work the same way as return inside of the `render() {}` function in a class-based component.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return(
    <div>Some stuff inside</div>
  )
}
```

Here's a class based version of it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Some stuff inside</div>;
  }
}
```